# NSLayoutConstraint change not working

Tags: ios

I have the code below for changing `NSLayoutConstraint` with delay. The value is changing but without delay and animation. Please let me know what is the issue with this code.

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 100;
[self.animatingView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [self.animatingView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Comment: remove     [self.animatingView layoutIfNeeded];
 from your code. and check

Comment: @Nirmalsinh: not work even after removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling layoutIfNeeded method on the superview of animatingView.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and it is working. But, why superview.

Comment: You need to call it specifically on the parent view, not the child view that has the constraints attached to it. Doing so will update all constrained views, including animating other views that might be constrained to the view that you changed the constraint of.

Answer (score 0):

Remvoe this line

`[self.animatingView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`

It will update without animation  and 
change

```
[self.animatingView layoutIfNeeded]; to

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{    
self.heightConstraint.constant = 100;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

this will work